# Как изменить вывод текста с id классом?

Tags: javascript, jquery

после удачной операции скрипт который выводит
 `<span style="color:#0FB10F">Сохранено</span>` в произвольной форме где попало,
как вывести его именно конкретно в `<div id="block">`

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.this_desc').blur(function(){
        this_desc = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:ajaxurl,
            data:'action=updateDescr&description_val=' + this_desc.val() + '&page_id=' + this_desc.attr('data-id'),
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                this_desc.attr('readonly','readonly').next().html('Сохраняю...');
            },
            success:function(results){
                this_desc.removeAttr('readonly').next().html('<span style="color:#0FB10F">Сохранено</span>');
            }
        }); 
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#block').html('<span style="color:#0FB10F">Сохранено</span>');
```